# update emp_id column with 1 billion records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an EMP table with columns

```
emp_id(number(10)), ename varchar2(25) and DOB (date)
```

The count of records = 1billion.

The emp_id column is totally null and I have to fill it with unique values.

What are the 3 easy steps to complete the task?
Help me with Oracle PL/SQL code to finish this task.

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 steps:

```sql
ALTER TABLE emp DROP COLUMN emp_id;
ALTER TABLE emp ADD (emp_id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eb8b7192501cb693e6c619d6b98901e9)*

---

Again, 2 steps:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE emp__emp_id__seq;

UPDATE emp
SET emp_id = emp__emp_id__seq.NEXTVAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=88101fc7880875c286e477cf06f8f88b)*

---

One step:

If you have overwritten the column data then either `ROLLBACK` the last transaction or restore the data from backups.

Comment: Thank You for your update MTD. 
Step #2 works fine for my oracle 12c DB. 

If you have alternate approaches, kindly let me know
Thank YOU in advance

Answer (score 1):

> The emp_id column is totally null and I have to fill it with unique values.

If you want to do it one-time-only, then just **one step** would do:

```
update emp set emp_id = rownum;
```

and that column will have *unique values*. You don't need PL/SQL (but be patient as 1 billion rows is quite a lot, it'll take time).

---

If you want to automatically populate it in the future, then it depends on database version you use. Before 12c, you'll have to use a sequence and a database trigger. In later versions, you can still use the same (sequence + trigger) or - as MT0 showed - identity column.